# A $q$-Pochhammer integral: $\int_0^\infty\!\frac1{1+x}\frac2{2+x}\frac4{4+x}\frac8{8+x}\cdots\,dx=\log2$

Tags: integration, special-functions

**Question**: Show that for any $a>1$, we have
$$\int_0^\infty\!\frac{dx}{(1+x)(1+\frac xa)(1+\frac x{a^2})(1+\frac x{a^3})\cdots}\overset?=\log a.$$

WolframAlpha is able to [evaluate specific instances of the above integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5B1%2FProduct%5B1%2Bx%2F2%5En%2C%7Bn%2C0%2CInfinity%7D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2CInfinity%7D%5D) numerically, but not symbolically.

For fixed $a>1$, denote the integrand by $f_a(x)$. It is not hard to check that $f_a$ is characterised by the following properties:

- $f_a:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is continuous;
- $f_a(0)=1$;
- $(1+x)f_a(x)=f_a(\frac xa)$ for all $x>0$.

We also have other identities relating the integrands for different values of $a$, eg. $f_a(x)=f_{a^2}(x)f_{a^2}(\frac xa)$.

In fact, we can write $f_a(x)$ in terms of the [q-Pochhammer symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html), namely
$$f_a(x)=\frac1{\left(-x;\frac1a\right)_\infty}.$$

It is not clear to me that the desired identity is an easy consequence of above functional equations and relations. It is also not obvious how to set up the usual tools for 1D definite integrals (Feynman trick, complex contour integration, ...).

Comment: Is it an assignment ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't think one should care on this particular occasion, honestly. The context is very nice, and I think you should have a go if you can.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer. I tried a lot, be sure. I wonder if we could use the k-gamma function f some hypergeometric representation. It is a nice problem (I upvoted the question) but, one more, I am stuck. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Good luck with the problem!

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer. This is simple : use partial fraction decomposition for the infinite product, integrate (simple) recombine the logarithms and use the bounds ! (joke for sure)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I came up with the integral when creating problems for an integration bee. Of course, by now it's clear that this integral is too hard for a timed test, but I'm still curious about a solution.

Comment: @chronondecay I wonder if this would work, but my efforts consisted of finding a power series expansion for this product. The good news is that if this integral were from $0$ to $1$, say, then I believe you can get a closed form. I'll have to check that properly, but it could work out.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer See the [identities in the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol#Identities). It's not clear how to deal with the $\exp(-O(x^2))$ decay near $\infty$, in the same way that I don't see how to show $\int_0^\infty\!e^{-x}\,dx=1$ using its Taylor series around $x=0$.

Comment: @chronondecay I agree, that's the difficult part of your question.

Answer (score 7):

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a > 1$ let
$$ I_n (a) = \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\prod \limits_{k=0}^n (1 + x/a^k)} \, . $$
Partial fractions lead to
\begin{align*}
I_n (a) &= \int \limits_0^\infty \left[\sum \limits_{k=0}^n \left(\prod \limits_{k \neq l = 0}^n (1 - a^{k-l})^{-1} \right) \frac{1}{1+x/a^k}\right] \mathrm{d} x \\
&= \lim_{r \to \infty} \sum \limits_{k=0}^n a^k \left(\prod \limits_{k \neq l = 0}^n (1 - a^{k-l})^{-1} \right) \log(1+r/a^k) \\
&= \lim_{r \to \infty} \sum \limits_{k=0}^n a^k \left(\prod \limits_{k \neq l = 0}^n (1 - a^{k-l})^{-1} \right) [\log(r) - k \log(a)] \, .
\end{align*}
Now we rewrite
\begin{align}
a^k \prod \limits_{k \neq l = 0}^n (1 - a^{k-l})^{-1} &= \left(\prod \limits_{m=1}^n (1-a^{-m})^{-1}\right) (-1)^k a^{-k(k-1)/2} \prod \limits_{m=1}^k \frac{1 - a^{-(n-m+1)}}{1 - a^{-m}} \\
&= \left(\prod \limits_{m=1}^n (1-a^{-m})^{-1}\right) (-1)^k a^{-k(k-1)/2} \binom{n}{k}_{1/a}
\end{align}
in terms of the [Gaussian binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient). The corresponding [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#q-binomial_theorem) allows us to compute the sum over $k$:
\begin{align}
I_n(a) &= \left(\prod \limits_{m=1}^n (1-a^{-m})^{-1}\right) \lim_{r \to \infty} \sum \limits_{k=0}^n [\log(r) - k \log(a)] (-b)^k a^{-k(k-1)/2} \binom{n}{k}_{1/a} \, \Bigg \vert_{b=1} \\
&= \left(\prod \limits_{m=1}^n (1-a^{-m})^{-1}\right) \lim_{r \to \infty} \left[\log(r) - \log(a) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}b}\right] \prod \limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (1 - b a^{-k}) \, \Bigg \vert_{b=1} \\
&= \left(\prod \limits_{m=1}^n (1-a^{-m})^{-1}\right) \log(a) \prod \limits_{k=1}^{n-1} (1 - a^{-k}) \\
&= \frac{\log(a)}{1-a^{-n}} \, .
\end{align}
For your integral the dominated convergence theorem implies
$$ \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\prod \limits_{k=0}^\infty (1 + x/a^k)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} I_n (a) = \log(a) $$
as conjectured.

---

Given the simple result for $I_n (a)$, I had hoped for a more 'straightforward' proof. Some ideas:

1. A contour integral approach yields $$ I_n(a) = \sum \limits_{k=0}^n \operatorname{Res} \left(z \mapsto \frac{-\log(-z)}{\prod \limits_{l=0}^n (1+z/a^l)},-a^k\right) \, , $$ which is clearly equivalent to the partial fractions method.
2. Using [Feynman parametrisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization), we can derive $$ I_n (a) = (n-1)! \int \limits_{\Delta_n} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1 - \sum \limits_{k=1}^n (1-a^{-k}) u_k} \, , $$ where $\Delta_n = \{u \in [0,1]^n : \sum_{k=1}^n u_k \leq 1\}$. I have not been able to compute the remaining integral for arbitrary $n$.